# Share Post only works from Facebook developer

Tags: android, facebook

My app uses Facebook's  SDK, to login and share posts.
I can already log in, but when prb is share, I can share only from the Facebook developer, all other users can't share. 
I already made this app public and available to all users. It takes the permission publish_actions,
and all code is correct, because this already works from my account. When I searched I found that to make all user share must 
start a new permission from Facebook developer and enable publish_actions, so could this be the issue?
When I try to make this, I did all the steps, but in the last one I need the Privacy Policy URL, and I don't know what this means. Could someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting April 30th of 2015, Facebook requires reviews for the apps that need extended permissions - publish_actions is one of those permissions that require reviewing by the Facebook Team.

You can submit your app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) for review.

Remember, the review process might take a few days to one week!

Good luck!

Comment: how can get Privacy Policy URL??

Comment: You will have to provide a URL from your website that has your privacy policy (if you have any). I do not think it is required!

Comment: it is required , to enable publish_actions , must make some steps  1- upload apk , 2- put some notes about aplication , 3 -then put Privacy Policy URL

Comment: do you mean it is only , url to my web site ?

Comment: Yes should be a URL to your private policy